# Ionic 3 and Razorpay - can we use the same Cordova plugin for web app

Tags: web, ionic-framework, ionic3, razorpay

I have integrated Razorpay in my Ionic 3 application using the Cordova plugin at https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git.

I am using my Ionic 3 app as a web application also. It's working perfectly fine on mobiles.

What should I do to make it work in web?

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to test your app on browser with cordova functionality hit,

```
>cordova run browser
```

Comment: I ran the below demo application
https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova-sample-app/tree/master/rzp-ionic3-example
using cordova run browser, It ran in browser. But I am getting the error.
"RazorpayCheckout is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Add a file in your src folder by the name "declaration.d.ts" and add the below code

```
declare var RazorpayCheckout: any;
```